# Elastic does not search if one of the entries is empty

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this code and it works great:

```
   res = es.search(index="myindex", 
        body={
            "from" : 0, "size" : 100, "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [{
                        "match": { 'p_name': p_name},
                        "match": { 'p_desc': p_desc},
                        "match": { 'p_ingr': p_ingr}
                        }]}}})
```

But sometimes p_desc or p_ingr is empty and elastic for such records does not search.

Can I put that elastic performed search for such records?

Comment: It wont search because that would not be valid JSON. You could have 'empty' variables if you wrapped them in quotes like `{
 "p_name": ' " ' + pname ' " '
}`
using whatever string concaternation/quote espcaing your language supports

Comment: @IanGabes In my case empty is '', not None. It must be valid.

Comment: Do you get an error, or no results?

Comment: @IanGabes no results. Maybe the reason is not it?

Comment: did the solution work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for empty strings with [`script`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/query-dsl-script-query.html) using `empty` on field. Try this

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "p_name": p_name
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "p_desc": p_desc
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "p_ingr": p_ingr
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": {
              "script": {
                "script": "doc['p_desc'].empty || doc['p_ingr'].empty"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This query will return results where `p_desc` or `p_ingr` is an empty string i.e `""`